# Viewing a ASP.NET page inside Web Application Project without building the whole project

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to view the change of a page inside Web Application Project **without building** the whole web application project and its dependent library projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to build any referenced projects (unless you have made changes in them), but you will need to build the web project

That's the big advantage of the web site model, which supports partial compilation:

Well described here:

http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/aspnetcompilation/aspnetcompilation.asp

Comment: Hi, every time I build the web project, it'll fisrt build dependent projects. It looks like this is due to project dependency setting. Do you know how to work around this?

Comment: It's been a while since I used the web application model. Are you building, or rebuilding? Building will build only the necessary projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the change of a page without re-building the whole project only if you change a front end of a page. After changing front end, save it, and then refresh browser. If back end changes, you will need to re-build the whole application.